# What data structure should I use for BigInt class

Tags: c++, math, data-structures, biginteger

I would like to implement a BigInt class which will be able to handle really big numbers. I want only to add and multiply numbers, however the class should also handle negative numbers.

I wanted to represent the number as a string, but there is a big overhead with converting string to int and back for adding. I want to implement addition as on the high school, add corresponding order and if the result is bigger than 10, add the carry to next order.

Then I thought that it would be better to handle it as a array of unsigned long long int and keep the sign separated by bool. With this I'm afraid of size of the int, as C++ standard as far as I know guarantees only that int < float < double. Correct me if I'm wrong. So when I reach some number I should move in array forward and start adding number to the next array position.

Is there any data structure that is appropriate or better for this?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable implementation to me.  But if you're using ULONGs, each element in the array can hold a value from 0 to 2^32-1 instead of from 0 to 10.  That should save you a few bytes. :-)

Comment: The standard guarantees only `float <= double` (note the equal sign)

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I meant. But is 2^32 - 1 the same on linux and on solaris? Respectively is the size guaranteed everywhere? My point is, that for example I get MyBigIntClass number = "234567434256547"; , and I start converting this string number to my inner representation in the class which is usigned long long int(maybe :-) ), and after the number reaches 2^32 I move to another position in array. Is it correct?

Comment: Use 2-complement for the negative numbers, not a sign bit. This way you don't need to handle signed arithmetic specially. Also, if you are doing this for personal fun, then go ahead (it *is* fun to write a bigint class, especially multiplication via FFT and division with Newton method). If you just need a bigint class which works, look at the excellent Gnu MP library (and the related MPFR).

Comment: I'm doing it as a homework. Hopefully I don't need division:-)

Answer (score 5):

So, you want a dynamic array of integers of a well known size?

Sounds like `vector<uint32_t>` should work for you.

Comment: unfortunately STL is not allowed

Comment: homework? embedded? In any case, you will need something like `vector`. Fortunately, it's a simple exercise to recreate a basic "dynamic array."

Answer (score 2):

As you already found out, you will need to use specific types in your platform (or the language if you have C++11) that have a fixed size. A common implementation of big number would use 32bit integers and ensure that only the lower 16 bits are set. This enables you to operate on the *digits* (where digit would be [0..2^16) ) and then *normalize* the result by applying the carry-overs.

Comment: For addition / substraction, carry can be done on the way and you don't need two passes. For multiplication, it depends on the algorithm, but if you're using eg. floating point FFT methods, you don't need carries too (but it is better to use 16 bit "digits" since you'll accumulate roundoff error during the FFT).

Answer (score 2):

On a modern, 64-bit x86 platform, the best approach is probably to store your bigint as a dynamically-allocated array of unsigned 32-bit integers, so your arithmetic can fit in 64 bits.  You can handle your sign separately, as a member variable of the class, or you can use 2's-complement arithmetic (which is how `signed int`'s are typically represented).

The standard C `<stdint.h>` include file defines `uint32_t` and `uint64_t`, so you can avoid platform-dependent integer types.  Or, (if your platform doesn't provide these), you can improvise and define this kind of thing yourself -- preferably in a separate `"platform_dependent.h"` file...

Comment: 2-s complement is not easy to do for dynamic length bigints (and doesn't buy much), but I agree with the rest.